# Understanding Stream Redirecting in Code File - Reading from `stdin`

Tags: c

This Question is based on the code at: http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/

The below code, behaves as I would expect. It echo's back User Input from: `stdin`.

> stdin: The standard input stream is the default source of data for applications. In most systems, it is usually directed by default to the keyboard.

Type in text and press enter, that text echo's back to the console. Normal, and expected.

```
// _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS:
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

// Char as int:
int ch;

// File Pointer:
FILE *fid;

// Open the File: Stream
fid = fopen("<Path to simple text file>/text.txt", "r");

// Loop through Chars:
while (1)
{

// Check valid Stream:
if (fid == NULL)
{
printf("Stream Error: File was not opened!\n");
break;
}

// If EOF:
if (feof(fid))
{
break;
}

// Get C:
ch = fgetc(fid);

// Print C:
printf("%c", ch);
}

// Close the File:
fclose(fid);


// Open the File: Stream
fid = stdin;

// Loop through Chars:
while (1)
{

// Check valid Stream:
if (fid == NULL)
{
printf("Stream Error: File was not opened!\n");
break;
}

// If EOF:
if (feof(fid))
{
break;
}

// Get C:
ch = fgetc(fid);

// Print C:
printf("%c", ch);
}


int i = 0;

return i;
}
```

**EXAMPLE Source code:** http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/ - Specifically from Line 301 of the **coocur.c** Code File

In this code:

```
fid = fopen(vocab_file,"r");
if(fid == NULL) {fprintf(stderr,"Unable to open vocab file %s.\n",vocab_file); return 1;}
while(fscanf(fid, format, str, &id) != EOF) hashinsert(vocab_hash, str, ++j); // Here id is not used: inserting vocab words into hash table with their frequency rank, j
fclose(fid);
vocab_size = j;
j = 0;
if(verbose > 1) fprintf(stderr, "loaded %lld words.\nBuilding lookup table...", vocab_size);

/* Build auxiliary lookup table used to index into bigram_table */
lookup = (long long *)calloc( vocab_size + 1, sizeof(long long) );
if (lookup == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't allocate memory!");
    return 1;
}
lookup[0] = 1;
for(a = 1; a <= vocab_size; a++) {
    if((lookup[a] = max_product / a) < vocab_size) lookup[a] += lookup[a-1];
    else lookup[a] = lookup[a-1] + vocab_size;
}
if(verbose > 1) fprintf(stderr, "table contains %lld elements.\n",lookup[a-1]);

/* Allocate memory for full array which will store all cooccurrence counts for words whose product of frequency ranks is less than max_product */
bigram_table = (real *)calloc( lookup[a-1] , sizeof(real) );
if (bigram_table == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't allocate memory!");
    return 1;
}

fid = stdin; // <<<--- STDIN Stream Redirect
sprintf(format,"%%%ds",MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
sprintf(filename,"%s_%04d.bin",file_head, fidcounter);
foverflow = fopen(filename,"w");
if(verbose > 1) fprintf(stderr,"Processing token: 0");

/* For each token in input stream, calculate a weighted cooccurrence sum within window_size */
while (1) {
    if(ind >= overflow_length - window_size) { // If overflow buffer is (almost) full, sort it and write it to temporary file
        qsort(cr, ind, sizeof(CREC), compare_crec);
        write_chunk(cr,ind,foverflow);
        fclose(foverflow);
        fidcounter++;
        sprintf(filename,"%s_%04d.bin",file_head,fidcounter);
        foverflow = fopen(filename,"w");
        ind = 0;
    }
    flag = get_word(str, fid); // <<<--- Reading from the Vocab, not STDIN
    if(feof(fid)) break;
    if(flag == 1) {j = 0; continue;} // Newline, reset line index (j)
    counter++;
    if((counter%100000) == 0) if(verbose > 1) fprintf(stderr,"\033[19G%lld",counter);
    htmp = hashsearch(vocab_hash, str); // <<<--- Using the str that was read in the function: 'get_word'
    if (htmp == NULL) continue; // Skip out-of-vocabulary words
    w2 = htmp->id; // Target word (frequency rank)
    for(k = j - 1; k >= ( (j > window_size) ? j - window_size : 0 ); k--) { // Iterate over all words to the left of target word, but not past beginning of line
        w1 = history[k % window_size]; // Context word (frequency rank)
        if ( w1 < max_product/w2 ) { // Product is small enough to store in a full array
            bigram_table[lookup[w1-1] + w2 - 2] += 1.0/((real)(j-k)); // Weight by inverse of distance between words
            if(symmetric > 0) bigram_table[lookup[w2-1] + w1 - 2] += 1.0/((real)(j-k)); // If symmetric context is used, exchange roles of w2 and w1 (ie look at right context too)
        }
        else { // Product is too big, data is likely to be sparse. Store these entries in a temporary buffer to be sorted, merged (accumulated), and written to file when it gets full.
            cr[ind].word1 = w1;
            cr[ind].word2 = w2;
            cr[ind].val = 1.0/((real)(j-k));
            ind++; // Keep track of how full temporary buffer is
            if(symmetric > 0) { // Symmetric context
                cr[ind].word1 = w2;
                cr[ind].word2 = w1;
                cr[ind].val = 1.0/((real)(j-k));
                ind++;
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to know, how exactly, a word is assigned to `str` in the method: `flag = get_word(str, fid);` after the stream has been changed to `stdin`, which is then used two lines later: `htmp = hashsearch(vocab_hash, str);`

This Code does many millions of iterations over large Corpora, a user does not sit there and type in each word manually.

I would very much appreciate if someone could explain how this is occurring, after the: `fid = stdin;` Stream change.

Comment: `stdin` isn't necessarily the keyboard.

Comment: If after this `fid = stdin;`, this `... = get_word(str, fid);` doesn't read from standard input then `stdin` had been modified way *before* this `fid = stdin;`.

Comment: @alk - Agreed, I am failing to see `stdin` redirect code. To me this is currently illusive. Of course, 27 Lines before: `fid = fopen(vocab_file,"r");` which is the file that is read from, the Vocab File.

Comment: You might want to compile the code with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on.

Comment: @alk - Yes, doing that now, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple to some, but not so for others...

`stdin` is a default Input Stream and thus in code can be directly accessed by using the `stdin` variable. So when one see's, and I have on a few occasions now:

```
FILE *fid;
fid = stdin;
```

The `stdin` stream has been redirected: "Somewhere" if this stream is not the default. Normally on most machines, the default is the Keyboard.

On line: 301 `fid = fopen(vocab_file,"r");` the vocab file becomes the stream data source, which is returned by the `fopen` function. The file is read and processed.

On line: 304 the stream is closed: `fclose(fid);`

On line: 329 `fid = stdin;` `stdin` is assigned as the input stream for `fid`.

From there, there is no sign of Stream Change, but there is assignment to `str`, this is from one of the text files, and the method: `get_word` assigns `str` from the corpora...

The command line input is the answer: ***-overflow-file tempoverflow < corpus.txt > cooccurrences.bin***

```
./cooccur -verbose 2 -symmetric 0 -window-size 10 -vocab-file vocab.txt -memory 8.0 -overflow-file tempoverflow < corpus.txt > cooccurrences.bin
```

Using : [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stdin/)

> Standard input stream
>
> The standard input stream is the default source of data for
>   applications. In most systems, it is usually directed by default to
>   the keyboard.
>
> stdin can be used as an argument for any function that expects an
>   input stream (FILE*) as one of its parameters, like fgets or fscanf.
>
> Although it is commonly assumed that the source of data for stdin is
>   going to be a keyboard, this may not be the case even in regular
>   console systems, since stdin can generally be redirected on most
>   operating systems at the time of invoking the application. For
>   example, many systems, among them DOS/Windows and most UNIX shells,
>   support the following command syntax:
>
> myapplication < example.txt
>
> to use the content of the file example.txt as the primary source of
>   data for myapplication instead of the console keyboard.
>
> It is also possible to redirect stdin to some other source of data
>   from within a program by using the freopen function.
>
> If stdin is known to not refer to an interactive device, the stream
>   is fully buffered. Otherwise, it is library-dependent whether the
>   stream is line buffered or not buffered by default (see setvbuf).

So there you go, the `stdin` stream is redirected by the command line argument: `-overflow-file tempoverflow < corpus.txt`

As a result: `corpus.txt` is the redirected data source of the `stdin` Stream!

Also worth noting, `cooccurrences.bin` is the redirected data source of the `stdout` Stream - vial Line: 232 `fout = stdout;` and written to on line: 270 `fwrite(&old, sizeof(CREC), 1, fout);`

For more information on: "[Standard Input and Output Redirection](http://sc.tamu.edu/help/general/unix/redirection.html)"

NOTE: If you want to run this code up, remember to set the Console App to 64 Bit - It wont allocate Memory other wise!

Comment: Down Voted, but not a single whisper of why - Some people  are miserable **MOFO's**

Comment: I think you are correct that it's because the coocur program expects input on stdin. I'd say it's not so nice, it would be better to allow the filename of the input text to be specified on the command line. Also, setting `fid = stdin` is confusing. All this makes answering this question hard. But maybe you can clarify your answer a bit?

Comment: @G.Sliepen - I agree, not so nice, its confusing! I have posted more information to my answer, please let me know if this is still not clear. I knew about the redirection processes but was not aware on how and where it was all done. Much of this appears to be very standard in Unix/Linux Systems, perhaps not so much in windows?

Comment: It is standard on Windows as well.